# Custom Media Player On Youtube Video Player Using Api

Tags: php, youtube-api, media-player

I want to know that is there any option that i can apply my own video player on youtube video player using iframe or youtube api ?

Comment: You cannot play YouTube hosted content in a non-YouTube player, and the URL source of a video is not exposed via the YouTube API. You can, however, use the iframe API (developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to embed a video without controls, and build your own control bar.

Comment: thanks jim so any other way i can use ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: okay jim but how much i can change youtube player using iframe api

Answer (score 0):

you can embed youtube video without control `controls=0` then wrapped it with your custom player and use it to control video using iframe api.

that's what I did on my jquery plugins, you can check it on github

https://github.com/qutek/FunkTube